# Locking Java task

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronization, locking

I tested running two tasks at the same time in my hibernate call. It incorrectly creates two objects with the same case number. I am wanting to lock this method until object1 gets its case number, and then object2 will get a different case number.

```
public String getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(String tenantId) {

        LOGGER.entering(getClass().getName(), "getNextCaseNumber");

            Configuration caseNumberStartValueConfiguration = null;
        List<Case> cases = null;

        try {
            caseNumberStartValueConfiguration = configurationService.getConfigurationByKey(ConfigurationKey.CASE_NUMBER_START_VALUE, tenantId);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        try {
            cases = caseService.getAllCases(tenantId);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        //LOCK DATABASE HERE
        synchronized(this) {
            // Get the largest case number in the database and increment from it
            int largestCaseNumber = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cases.size(); i++) {
                if (cases.get(i).getCaseNumber() != null) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(cases.get(i).getCaseNumber()) > largestCaseNumber) {
                        largestCaseNumber = Integer.parseInt(cases.get(i).getCaseNumber());
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set the case number to either the next largest number or the configured value, whichever is larger
            String caseNumber = "1";
            if (largestCaseNumber >= Integer.parseInt(caseNumberStartValueConfiguration.getConfigurationValue())) {
                caseNumber = Integer.toString(largestCaseNumber + 1);
            } else if (caseNumberStartValueConfiguration != null) {
                caseNumber = caseNumberStartValueConfiguration.getConfigurationValue();
            }


            LOGGER.exiting(getClass().getName(), "getNextCaseNumber");
            return caseNumber;
        }//END LOCK HERE

    }
```

As you can see I added the synchronized(this) { }
It is doing nothing. Any idea what I need to do differently to correctly lock this? Do I need to lock the entire method?

Comment: The 'this' is different in the two threads, so the synchronized isn't doing anything. A brute force approach would be to synchronize the entire method. Alternatively, you can have a static member object (in CaseHelper) and synchronize on that object (instead of 'this').

Comment: @MarkTucker I tried to make the method "public synchronized String getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(String tenantId)", but it still gives duplicate numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Doing synchronization this way

```
public synchronized String getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(String tenantId)  {

}
```

is the same as doing synchronization this way

```
public String getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(String tenantId)  {
    syncronized(this) {

    }    
}
```

Both cases use `this` to syncronize. As @MarkTucker suggested "the 'this' is different in the two threads so the synchronized isn't doing anything". You need a static field to synchronize on it

```
    private static Object sync = new Object();

    public String getNextCaseNumberFromDatabase(String tenantId)  {
        syncronized(sync) {

        }    
    }
```

But it is not the best way. Try to use only one row for a max case number in the database and get next case number in a transaction.

1. Open a transaction.
2. Get current case number with pessimistic locking (`LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` or similar, it depends on Hibernate
   version)

   `session.get(CaseNumber.class, caseNumberId, LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`
3. Increment a case number and update `CaseNumber`.
4. Commit a transaction.
5. Return an incremented case number.

Other threads will be wait until a transaction commit.